# reading multiple images in python

Tags: image

I want to read multiple images in python I'm using this code but when I run it,nothing happens.
Could you tell me what is the problem?

```
import glob , cv2
import numpy as np
def read_img(img_list , img):
    n=cv2.imread(img)
    img_list.append(n)
    return img_list
path = glob.glob("02291G0AR/*.bmp")
list_ = []
cv_image = [read_img(list_,img) for img in path]
print(cv_image)
```

"02291G0AR" is the folder where my images are save in. and it's near my code file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's just a matter of the print function not being the adequate one to use. I'd try:

```
for img in cv_image:
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but when I try your code I get this error:TypeError: mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar